# Cannot set output layer to classification

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently trying to implement a CNN which purpose is to perform classification, but for some reason am I not able to define my output dimension to 1.

Here is an example code:

```
import keras
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Lambda, Reshape,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Reshape, ZeroPadding2D
import numpy as np

train_data_1 = np.random.randint(100,size=(100,3,6,3))
train_data_2 = np.random.randint(100,size=(100,3,6,3))
test_data_1 = np.random.randint(100,size=(10,3,6,3))
test_data_2 = np.random.randint(100,size=(10,3,6,3))
labels_train_data =np.random.randint(145,size=100)
labels_test_data =np.random.randint(145,size=10)


input_img_1 = Input(shape=(3, 6, 3))
input_img_2 = Input(shape=(3, 6, 3))

conv2d_1_1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' , name = "conv2d_1_1" )(input_img_1)
conv2d_2_1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_1_1)
conv2d_3_1 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_2_1)
conv2d_4_1 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_3_1)
conv2d_4_1_flatten = Flatten()(conv2d_4_1)

conv2d_1_2 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' , name = "conv2d_1_2")(input_img_2)
conv2d_2_2 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_1_2)
conv2d_3_2 = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_2_2)
conv2d_4_2 = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1) , padding = "same" , activation = 'relu' )(conv2d_3_2)
conv2d_4_2_flatten = Flatten()(conv2d_4_2)


merge = keras.layers.concatenate([conv2d_4_1_flatten, conv2d_4_2_flatten])

dense1 = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(merge)
dense2 = Dense(50,activation = 'relu')(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(1 ,activation = 'softmax')(dense2)


model = Model(inputs = [input_img_1, input_img_2] , outputs = dense3)
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")

print model.summary()

labels_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_train_data, num_classes=145)
labels_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_test_data, num_classes=145)

hist_current = model.fit(x = [train_data_1, train_data_2],
                    y = labels_train,
                    shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=([test_data_1 ,test_data_2], labels_test),
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    epochs=150000,
                    batch_size = 15,
                    verbose=1)
```

And the error message being:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_model.py", line 57, in <module>
    verbose=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1405, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1299, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model target')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 133, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (100, 145)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several inconsistencies in your model :

1. `dense3 = Dense(1 ,activation = 'softmax')(dense2)` : you cannot use a softmax on one neuron alone. The softmax normalizese the output of the layer so that it sums up to 1... In this case if you normalize one value alone, it will always output 1. However this is not why you get the error
2. just how many classes do you have? From your network, you output one value (last layer is Dense(1)) so I would expect that you want to predict 2 classes (output 1 or 0). But here We see that your output is a categorical with 145 possibilities... Your `label_train` array is 100 one hot vectors of length 145, so I assume that you want to classify the 100 samples into 145 different categories... This is why keras is complaining, your networks outputs (100,1) and your targets (labels) are (100,145). What do you really want to do ?

**Edit :**

Following the comment, since you want to predictif the image belongs to one of 145 classes, you will have to output 145 values. So you will have to change the top layers of your network so that your last layer is a `Dense(145, activation='softmax')`. So I propose that you replace

```
dense1 = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(merge)
dense2 = Dense(50,activation = 'relu')(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(1 ,activation = 'softmax')(dense2)
```

with

```
dense1 = Dense(200, activation = 'relu')(merge)
dense2 = Dense(150, activation = 'relu')(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(145, activation = 'softmax')(dense2)
```

If you really want to have 3 dense layers, otherwise you can just remove the middle one... This will depend on your usecase, so the architecture of the hidden layers is up to you. I'm just insisting that your last layer should be a `Dense(145, activation='softmax')`.

Makes sense?

**Edit 2 :**

On top of that, you shouldn't encode your targets (labels) as categoricals, when you use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, it is done automatically under the hood.

So either you use `keras.utils.to_categorical` on your targets with `loss=categorical_crossentropy`

or you don't transform the targets with `keras.utils.to_categorical` and use `loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

It's running on my machine.

Comment: 1. Thanks! - That definitely needs to be corrected
2. I am basically doing classification on an image, i have 145 classes , the number of training_data is definitely larger than 100 (251058..), but for the question purposes I made this quick example.   The image is divided into sections, sections are certain parts of the image, in which a certain convolution is performed.  Certain in a sense that the weight are only shared in this local area.  Merge than concat all the features, and the fully connected layer supposed to perform classification based on the input.

Comment: I have edited my answer. For the record, when you use a Dense(1), use the 'sigmoid' activation to predict between two classes, or Dense(2, activation='softmax'), this is the same.

Comment: Can you copy paste the error? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Exactly the same as before.

Comment: That seemed to have been it! Thanks for the help :)